# Angular Material : on increasing mat stepper circle size the position of line is getting changed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-stepper

Kindly check my code snippet [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jogcrw-th6n48)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the below styles to make it work

```
.mat-step-header::after, .mat-step-header::before, .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
  top: 42px !important;
}
```

working example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jogcrw-wgpsoe?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually align either the head or the separator line. For the ease, I modified the head. On file `styles.scss`, after line 26, add this `top:-6px!important`. You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dragos